# Can we use the badge system to encourage keeping comments tidy?

Tags: feature-request, comments, badge-request

Looking at the current [comment privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) page, and reflecting on the effort that must go into dealing with comment flags, I wonder whether we could use the Badge system to encourage people to tidy up their own comments, rather than rely on moderators to find and delete comments which no longer serve the community.

We already have the [commentator](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator) and [pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/94/pundit) badges to encourage people to use the comment system, but I wonder if a *Scout* tag or something similar might be appropriate to encourage the deletion of obsolete comments.

Just as the Scout Rule says "*Always leave the camp ground cleaner than you found it*", this badge would be granted for deleting (tidying up) say 10 of your own comments.

In accordance with the [Positive Badge Rule](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/), this might encourage people to get into the habit of tidying up their comments when appropriate.

<sup>Related to [Need a way to clean up obsolete comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57344/138432).</sup>

Comment: But how would you be able to tell _why_ a comment was deleted (might not be because it was obsolete)?

Comment: There's no way that people would post junk comments just to delete them and get the badge, right?

Comment: Does this mean that the mod queue will be chock a block full of "obsolete" "chatty" and other hard-to-judge comment flags?

Comment: @Oded - I don't think you'd need to try to keep track of *why* a comment was deleted. The point is to try to encourage people to tidy up after themselves. Good habits learnt early on stay with poeple.

Comment: @GhostofChristmasPresents - Do people post 10 junk comments just to get the *Commentator* badge? If so, then a *Boy Scout* badge would probably encourage just those sort of people to remove them. *8')

Answer (score 5):

I like the motivation, but I don't know how you make this not easy to game and relatively easy to implement. I think there'd have to be some minimum time limit for the comment to live after posting, which seems like an awful lot of work for very little gain.

It's probably better to get people to flag obsolete comments and to get trusted users to act on those flags.

But, then again, comments are second-class citizens around here. I wouldn't expect too much work done there.

Comment: We already have [Peer Pressure](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure), which isn't exactly difficult to game

Answer (score 0):

There are already badges for useful flags, and you can flag such comments as obsolete.
You can't flag your own comments, but you can tidy up after everyone else and be rewarded by a shiny thing.

This means that there is already a badge incentive to keep comments tidy.
It excludes your own comments, but that just serves to exclude gaming.
Someone else can flag your obsolete comments as obsolete if they want the badge.
(This might be less desirable on large sites, but perhaps the review process for deleting flagged comments could be redesigned.)

If you get a reward for deleting your own comments, the system is easy to game.
If you get a reward for flagging other users' comments after your flags are approved, abuse is way harder.
The current flag badges incentivize something that is almost surely beneficial.

Comment: With my (protem) moderator hat on, I don't want people to flag other peoples obsolete comments, which I then have to verify and act on, I want people to get into the habit of deleting their own obsolete comments. *8')

Comment: @MarkBooth Fair enough. I'm a protem moderator on such a small site that such flags would be no issue, but I realize the workload does not scale well for bigger sites.

Comment: @MarkBooth When your site gets as many comments as mine does, you depend on the kindness of others' no longer needed flags if you want to keep the comments sections neat. We easily delete 1000 comments per month.

Comment: What have you got to lose by encouraging people to tidy up their own comments then @Catija ? I'm certainly not going to argue with the 'my site is bigger than yours' argument, I was just trying to suggest something which might encourage people to do things which will lighten the load for moderators on sites of all sizes.

Comment: @MarkBooth Nothing. But expecting it to happen is... a great way to end up with a bunch of extra comments. Clearly they think this is a reasonable idea. They included it as a Hat trigger for Winter Bash.